# Issue with spaces in a string after posting it to a uri using System.Net.WebClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I have a string which have some spaces in it

```
String strValue = "TESTDATA      "
```

and am sending this data to a uri using the below code

`Using client As New System.Net.WebClient
                client.Headers(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType) = "application/json"
                result = client.UploadString(uri, "POST", strValue )
            End Using`

But after posting the data successfully when i check the data the spaces are not included in it. It is like

```
strValue = "TESTDATA"
```

I need to include the spaces also like `strValue = "TESTDATA     "`.
Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding it first

```
strValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strValue);
```

Comment: I have used what you have suggested and when i check the data after posting it is like 

`strValue = "TESTDATA&#43;&#43;&#43;&#43;&#43;"`

Thanks

Comment: Then I think you need to decode it before consuming `strValue = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(strValue);`